# write sql query in different way

Tags: mysql, sql

how can i write this query in different ways:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS patient_count FROM 
(select * from patient_score GROUP BY patient_id, service_date_end) AS p
 JOIN map_cohort_patient AS m ON p.patient_id = m.patient_id 
WHERE cohort_id = UUID_TO_BIN_F("38f58f93-b80d-4a54") 
AND service_date_end = "2021-07-31"
```

Comment: One way is simply to not put it all in one line, so it is easier to read

Comment: Why do need different ways? Is there an issue with your query?

Comment: SELECT * if you onply need th id isn't a good idea

Comment: this query is taking alot of execution time @HoneyBadger

Comment: Then why did you not say that? If you want people to help you, give them the information they need to be able to help you

Comment: Count always takes a lot of time

Comment: @nbk "a lot of time" is subjective of course, and I have to admit I don't have much experience in mysql, but I very much doubt a `select count(*)` would be slower, let alone much, or even noticeable slower, then a `select {column_list}`

Comment: it was closed to fast try https://dbfiddle.uk/3aMmxpPT

Answer (score 1):

Since you only want a specific `service_date_end`, you should put that in the subquery, rather than getting all the dates and then filtering.

Since you only care about the `patient_id`, just select that and use `DISTINCT` to get rid of the duplicates.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS patient_count
FROM map_cohort_patient AS m
JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT patient_id
    FROM patient_score
    WHERE service_date_end = '2021-07-31'
) AS p ON p.patient_id = m.patient_id
WHERE m.cohort_id = UUID_TO_BIN_F("38f58f93-b80d-4a54")
```

If the subquery is slow, you should add an index on `service_date_end` so it doesn't require a full scan.

Comment: Sorry, copy/paste error when I swapped the order

Comment: A `WHERE EXISTS` might be quicker still

Comment: Possibly. I've always been suspicious of MySQL optimization of correlated subqueries, since it often gets `WHERE id IN (SELECT ...)` horribly wrong and they're similar.